# Reload page, but keep DOM saved

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please help me in following case.
Have a page on which exiss click button with 7 options in it.
Found those seven options and save it in a list

> WebElement List

Wanted to use **for loop** in order to pickup every element and check if every button is cliked.

Now comes tricky part:
That dropdwon is not **Select one** type and is shown after click on button named **Report**

[image]

So, in summary I have first to click to open dropdown (on **Report** button),
 then choose one option

[image]

and after that message on page appears such is:

```
report sent succesfully or error
```

[image]

But, button for activating dropdown disapper (after click on sending report) and will not appear again until page has been reloaded.

In order to choose next option I must reload page, but then I loose saved options and iteration is uselless.
Tried reloading page with

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

As a result, I have one pass in loop and after that error:

```
stale element exception element still exists no DOM attached, the reference is lost
```

So, my question: Is there any other way in Java & Selenium to keep DOM and reload same page in a same time?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Use fluent wait and try to catch stale error there till BOM not loaded properly

Comment: @ Ankur Singh Sorry not follwoing you. Will add screesnhots of how it is looksl ike for better understanding of an issue

Comment: @ Ankur Singh Added screenshots (first before opening dropdown second wjhen opened and third when sent report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to refetch the collection of options inside the loop and access it by index.

```
By buttonLocator = By.id(""); // the button that when clicked exposes the dropdown
By optionsLocator = By.id(""); // the options in the dropdown
driver.findElement(buttonLocator).click();
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(optionsLocator);
for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++)
{
    driver.findElements(By.id("")).get(i).click(); // click the option
    // code that detects success or error
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}
```